# Script exported from ModelBuilder gives ERROR 000733 at SelectByLocation?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I created a model in ModeBbuilder, and I exported the model as a script, but when I try to run it I get the following error. I have added my error below and the code below that. Thanks for any help.

> Error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Temp\VirtualCampus\IGIS\IGISprogrammingscript_1.py", line 43, in
>   
>       arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Points_of_interest, Pointsofinterest_Layer, "", "", "FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape
>   VISIBLE NONE;CATEGORY CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;NAME NAME VISIBLE NONE")
>   File "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py",
>   line 5774, in MakeFeatureLayer
>       raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000733: Output Layer: Same as input
>   C:\Temp\VirtualCampus\IGIS\Super Output Areas.shp Failed to execute
>   (MakeFeatureLayer).

Here is my code:

```
~# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IGISprogrammingscript_1.py
# Created on: 2013-07-09 21:39:46.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Usage: IGISprogrammingscript_1 <Thames_shp> <Points_of_interest> <Super_Output_Areas_shp> <Thames_Buffer_shp> <superoutputareas_clip_shp> 
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
Thames_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if Thames_shp == '#' or not Thames_shp:
    Thames_shp = "C:\\Temp\\VirtualCampus\\IGIS\\Thames.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

Points_of_interest = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if Points_of_interest == '#' or not Points_of_interest:
    Points_of_interest = "Points of interest" # provide a default value if unspecified

Super_Output_Areas_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
if Super_Output_Areas_shp == '#' or not Super_Output_Areas_shp:
    Super_Output_Areas_shp = "C:\\Temp\\VirtualCampus\\IGIS\\Super Output Areas.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

Thames_Buffer_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
if Thames_Buffer_shp == '#' or not Thames_Buffer_shp:
    Thames_Buffer_shp = "C:\\Temp\\VirtualCampus\\IGIS\\Thames_Buffer.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

superoutputareas_clip_shp = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)
if superoutputareas_clip_shp == '#' or not superoutputareas_clip_shp:
    superoutputareas_clip_shp = "C:\\Temp\\VirtualCampus\\IGIS\\superoutputareas_clip.shp" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
Pointsofinterest_Layer__2_ = Thames_Buffer_shp
poi_cat = Pointsofinterest_Layer__2_
poi_cat_View = poi_cat
Pointsofinterest_Layer = Points_of_interest
pop = superoutputareas_clip_shp
pop_View = pop

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Points_of_interest, Pointsofinterest_Layer, "", "", "FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;CATEGORY CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;NAME NAME VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Buffer
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Thames_shp, Thames_Buffer_shp, "300 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "")

# Process: Select Layer By Location
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Pointsofinterest_Layer, "COMPLETELY_WITHIN", Thames_Buffer_shp, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

# Process: Summary Statistics
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(Pointsofinterest_Layer__2_, poi_cat, "CATEGORY COUNT", "CATEGORY")

# Process: Make Table View
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(poi_cat, poi_cat_View, "", "", "CATEGORY CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;FREQUENCY FREQUENCY VISIBLE NONE;COUNT_CATEGORY COUNT_CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Clip
arcpy.Clip_analysis(Super_Output_Areas_shp, Thames_Buffer_shp, superoutputareas_clip_shp, "")

# Process: Summary Statistics (2)
arcpy.Statistics_analysis(superoutputareas_clip_shp, pop, "LSOA_POP SUM", "")

# Process: Make Table View (2)
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(pop, pop_View, "", "", "Rowid Rowid VISIBLE NONE;FID FID VISIBLE NONE;FREQUENCY FREQUENCY VISIBLE NONE;SUM_LSOA_POP SUM_LSOA_POP VISIBLE NONE")~
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for MakeFeatureLayer are:

> MakeFeatureLayer_management (in_features, out_layer, {where_clause},
>   {workspace}, {field_info})

Your parameters don't seem to fit into this format. perhaps try fixing it

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Points_of_interest, Pointsofinterest_Layer, "", "", "FID FID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;CATEGORY CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;NAME NAME VISIBLE NONE")
```

not exactly sure what you are trying to get out of it.

does the line below fix your error?

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Points_of_interest", "Pointsofinterest_Layer")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried inputting your code, but it still produced the same error. I have three shapefiles, and am creating some new files from this, so a buffer, then using the buffer and one of the shapefiles to create a clip etc. I'm creating the model and then exporting the script, and running it in arc. The assignment is to create a model, export it as a python script, and import it as a script and in theory it should run like the model....

Comment: Try removing this line: Pointsofinterest_Layer = Points_of_interest